# Group by two columns to get sum of another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, sum

I look most of the previously asked questions but was not able to find answer for my question:

I have following dataframe

```
           id   year month score num_attempts
0      483625  2010    01   50      1
1      967799  2009    03   50      1
2      213473  2005    09  100      1
3      498110  2010    12   60      1
5      187243  2010    01  100      1
6      508311  2005    10   15      1
7      486688  2005    10   50      1
8      212550  2005    10  500      1
10     136701  2005    09   25      1
11     471651  2010    01   50      1
```

I want to get the following dataframe

```
year month sum_score sum_num_attempts
2009    03   50           1
2005    09  125           2
2010    12   60           1
2010    01  200           2
2005    10  565           3
```

Here is what I tried:

```py
sum_df = df.groupby(by=['year','month'])['score'].sum()
```

But this doesn't look efficient and correct. If I have more than one column need to be aggregate this seems like a very expensive call. for example if I have another column `num_attempts` and just want to sum by year month as score.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you think it's an expansive call, and what you would do with `num_attempts` if you want to keep it in the group operation?

Comment: @MaxU not sure if i understand the use of `as_index=False, what does that do?

Comment: sorry for my first comment - i've misunderstood you. What is wrong with: `df.groupby(['year','month'])[['score','num_attempts']].sum()` or `df.groupby(['year','month']).agg({'score':'sum', 'num_attempts':'max'})`?

Comment: @MaxU so will this create new columns in the resulting data frame if i want in a different column to reflect the results can I do that. Also my data frame is really large. is this the best way to carry out this task.

Comment: @Boud I have close to 9million records in this data frame and seems like its taking forever to get the results and I still haven't seen the final frame.

Comment: can you provide an example of your actual dataframe?

Comment: @DennisGolomazov just updated

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This should be an efficient way:

```
sum_df = df.groupby(['year','month']).agg({'score': 'sum', 'num_attempts': 'sum'})
```

Comment: Does the `score` column has to be explicitly integer?

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis I don't think so. If it doesn't work, will you elaborate?

Comment: The resulted sum_df only have the summed columns.

Comment: if anyone also wants to rename the column that gets created, so that the new(score) column doesn't take the same name as input column. append `.rename(columns={'score': 'score_sum_by_year_month'})` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to call `groupby.sum` on multiple columns and add prefix afterwards. This produces the desired column labels in the OP.

```py
sum_df = df.groupby(['year', 'month'])[['score', 'num_attempts']].sum().add_prefix('sum_').reset_index()
```

or use named aggregation from the beginning

```py
sum_df = df.groupby(['year', 'month'], as_index=False).agg(sum_score=('score', 'sum'), sum_num_attempts=('num_attempts', 'sum'))
```

Both produce the following frame:

[image: res]