# if I want to join the duplicated some columns in dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

```
col1 col2 col3
jake  male   180
jake  male    140
john   female 230
john   male    100
```

let say we have this kind of df 
if I want to group col1, and col2 and make new dataframe like this

```
col1 col2 col3
jake  male  [180,140]<-mean
john  female [230]<-mean
john  male   [100]<-mean
```

I tryied to use the group by

```
keyword_mean = df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col3'].agg(['mean']).reset_index()
```

but it keep making the duplicated col1 and col2

Comment: Check this works https://stackoverflow.com/a/40554037/5658251

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a pd.Series of the means without any group info, try:

```
df.groupby(["col1", "col2"]).mean().reset_index()["col3"]
```